# Stellaris TFT.h

Tags: arduino, stellaris

I would like to make connection between *Arduino Robot LCD* and *Stellaris LM4F*.

I have trouble with `TFT.h` file. There is a TFT library in Stellaris folder. However, there is always an error message when I compile codes. It says that No such file or directory TFT.

How can I add Arduino libraries to Stellaris . Or is there any way to use Arduino Robot LCD with Stellaris LM4F ?

Answer (score 0):

Try inluding the full path to the TFT.h file.

Or add the library via "*Add .ZIP Library*".